# Validate end_date is after start_date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with two date fields, `start_date` and `end_date`. I want to create a rule that `end_date` must be greater then `start_date`, and if this condition  returns `false` then to show validation errors as in the picture below.

[image]

So far I've tried to do so by creating a custom rule:

```
$.validator.addMethod("check_date", function(value, element) {
    var start_date = $("input[name='start_date']").val();
    var end_date = $("input[name='end_date']").val();
    return end_date(value) > start_date(value);
}, 'End date must be greater then start date.');
```

I'm not sure how exactly I set the rule and the message.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

```
   $.validator.addMethod("check_date", function(value, element) {
    var start_date = $("input[name='start_date']").val();
    var end_date = $("input[name='end_date']").val();
    return end_date > start_date;
}, 'End date must be greater then Start date.');
```